# for и загрузка процессора

Tags: golang

Собственно вопрос понятен из названия:
Есть программа с несколькими гоурутинами которые работают одновременно и постоянно и которым надо посылать друг в друга уведомления.
сейчас это:

```
botNotification := make(chan Notification, 1)

notification := Notification{Code: 1, TelegramID: user.TelegramID}
botNotification <- notification

for {
        select {
        case notification := <-botNotification:
            switch notification.Code {
            case 1:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.ManagerOpened)
            case 2:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.AdminOpened)
            default:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.NotFound)
            }
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
```

кроме того есть цикл for без условий для постоянной работы в фоне и возможности вводить простые команды вроде quit, statistics и подобных.

Ну и занимает это всё добро 102 процента vps'ного cpu постоянно. При запуске на рабочем компьютере (4 ядра) занимает 30%.

С этим что-то можно сделать кроме выставления таймингов (time.Sleep()) внутри каждого цикла?

Comment: то есть, есть цикл, который просто греет процессор? Вы хотите обрабатывать ввод пользователя с суперминимальными задержками?

Comment: @KoVadim ну в случае терминала я могу выставить срабатывание хоть каждые 5-10 секунд, не страшно. Но в случае с "уведомлениями" ну максимум секунда. Вопрос по сути не в том какие выставлять тайминги, а "есть ли какая-то разумная альтернатива им?"

Comment: уведомления, которые потоки шлют друг-дружке определяется задачей. Так как задача неизвестна, то и неизвестно, какие задержки есть правильные.

Comment: Разные потоки - несколько разных сайтов и ботов с общим чатом.

Comment: если никто не пишет сообщений, то похоже никто и не должен ничего никому слать. И нагрузка должна быть минимальной

Comment: Gohryt, а Вы попробуйте хотя бы задержку в 1 мс поставить в цикле и посмотреть загрузку в этом случае.

Comment: @Optimus1 при замене пустых форм на:
ticker := time.NewTicker
for range ricker.C
пожирание процессора не вырастает больше 2-3 процентов. Мне просто кажется что тайминги вручную - это как-то не умно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `select` не блокируется из-за `default: continue`

Всякий раз, когда программа проверяет наличие уведомления в канале, срабатывает select: если в канале что-то есть, то запускается обработчик, а если нет, то цикл продолжается.

Вам достаточно переписать цикл вот так:

```go
for {
        notification = <-botNotification

        switch notification.Code {
        case 1:
            c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.ManagerOpened)
        case 2:
            c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.AdminOpened)
        default:
            c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.NotFound)
        }
    }
```

Присваивание `notification = <-botNotification` блокируется до получения уведомления, поэтому цикл будет висеть в ожидании уведомления в канале и перестанет тратить CPU.

Если же вам по какой-то причине важно, чтобы цикл временами разблокировался, тогда нужно вместо `default` поставить таймаут:

```go
        select {
        case notification := <-botNotification:
            switch notification.Code {
            case 1:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.ManagerOpened)
            case 2:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.AdminOpened)
            default:
                c.SendChatAction(notification.TelegramID, tbot.ActionTyping)
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                c.SendMessage(notification.TelegramID, translation.NotFound)
            }
        case <-time.After(10*time.Second):
            fmt.Println("10 seconds of inactivity")
            continue
        }
```

Comment: уже переписал на for notification := range notifications {switch notification.Code{case 1: * default: *}}, вроде работает нормально и без перегрузок.

Comment: Да, так лучше. В любом случае, блокирующее чтение из канале останавливает цикл.